# How do I display a base64 image in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, base64, angular7

I want to take the base64 string and use it to display the image.
Below is the HTML file. I want to use the base64 string and use it in the img tag:

```js
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
      <img src={{imageFileBinary}} />
        <ion-card-header>
            <form>
                <ion-input id="myform" type="file" name="file" (change)="postMethod($event.target.files)"></ion-input>
            </form>
        <ion-card-title>Nick</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I get imageFileBinary from the .ts file.
Below is the .ts file:

```js
export class MyprofilePage implements OnInit {


  imageFileBinary;

  userDetails: UserDetails;
  constructor(private profileDetailService: ProfileDetailsService, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  fileToUpload;

  getProfileDetails() {
    this.profileDetailService.getUserDetails('email').subscribe((userDetails: UserDetails) => {
      this.imageFileBinary = userDetails.imageFileBinary
    });
  }
  postMethod(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);

    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/uploadFile", formData).subscribe((val)=> {
      console.log(val);
    });
    return false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfileDetails();

  }

}


How can I use the base64 String in the img tag?
```

Comment: Try something like this: `<img src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{imageFileBinary}}"/>`

Comment: That might not work when the image type is not known before downloading. (as it always assumes the data is "JPEG"). You should consider using DataUrl string which preserves the data type as well. (See my answer below)

Answer (score 6):

try this..

Convert your image binary data to base64 using javascript  btoa function and append it with data uri property.

```
imageUrl; //rename imageFileBinary to imageUrl

let imageBinary = userDetails.imageFileBinary; //image binary data response from api
let imageBase64String= btoa(imageBinary);
this.imageUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageBase64String;
```

Finally set it with angular data binding

```
<img src={{imageUrl}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the data you've downloaded to DataUrl to be able to use it as image source.

Here is a complete solution which downloads an image as base64 data url and shows to user:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <img [src]="quokkaData" />
    <img [src]="quokkaAsyncData | async" /> 
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public quokkaAsyncData: Observable<string>;
  public quokkaData: string;

  constructor(private httpSvc: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Method 1: Pass observer directly to template where "| async" is used.
    this.quokkaAsyncData = this.downloadDataAsBase64('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DR15b9eWAAEn7eo.jpg');

    // Method 2: Get data from subscriber and pass to image src
    this.downloadDataAsBase64('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DR15b9eWAAEn7eo.jpg')
      .subscribe((base64Data: string) => {
        this.quokkaData = base64Data;
      });
  }

  //#region Util methods

  private downloadDataAsBase64(url: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpSvc.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
      flatMap(blob => {
        return this.blobToBase64(blob);
      })
    );
  }

  private blobToBase64(blob: Blob): Observable<any> {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const observable = new Observable(observer => {
      fileReader.onloadend = () => {
        observer.next(fileReader.result);
        observer.complete();
      };
    });
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return observable;
  }

  //#region Util methods
}
```

And [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zeunxk) is a demo just in case it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

import DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl like this:

```
import {DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

define parameter and constructor:

```
picture: SafeResourceUrl;
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

sanitizer the base64:

```
this.picture = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
  'data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.imageFileBinary);
});
```

show in html:

```
<img src={{picture}} />
```

Comment: Could you explain why DomSanitizer is needed?

Comment: DomSanitizer helps preventing Cross Site Scripting Security bugs (XSS) by sanitizing values to be safe to use in the different DOM contexts.